# Instead of JSON data link is returning .txt file how to get JSON data in android

Tags: java, android, json, file, fetch

I am using a link when I open that link in the browser it generates a json.txt file and downloads it. I want to fetch this txt file in an android application and want to get JSON data from this txt file.

Comment: You can download the File to a specific folder in an Android device and fetch that file inside your code and extract the data form it as a Json.

Comment: @yash786 This is a real time application then storing file and fetching file takes too much time I want to handle this on runtime.

Comment: You can handle the things at runtime only no need to worry you have to download the file in Background thread and when downloading is finish then you can access the file and extract the Json Data from it.

Comment: @yash786 Can you please help me little how to download file in background and read it within the app. I did not found any help here. Because Every one is downloading the file and storing it.

Comment: Sure i'll help you let's go Step by Step.First try to download the file with the help of AsyncTask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new DownloadFileFromURL().execute("your_file_downloadable_url");

class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        System.out.println("Starting download");


    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

            System.out.println("Downloading");
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);

            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // getting file length
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            // Output stream to write file

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(root+"/downloadedfile.txt");
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);

            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }



    /**
     * After completing background task
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        System.out.println("Downloaded");

        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Comment: It is giving the security check while downloading the file and this is working fine in the browser.  2019-07-29 11:08:06.383 16000-16061/com.camera.pro.s10.procamera.app.downloadfile E/Error: Occure: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.google.com/sorry/index?continue=https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single%3Fclient%3Dgtx%26sl%3Den%26tl%3Dur%26dt%3Dt%26q%3DHi&q=EgRn_wVzGMaa-ukFIhkA8aeDS3w50q3Dt-bz_i8BjGEAxkJmJzvSMgFy

Comment: @MujahidRasool Off-course it will give an security check error you have to accept runtime permission to read and write storage.

Comment: @MujahidRasool I hope you have managed to download and store the file in your phone storage.? Yes then we can continue for next step to retrieve the file from local storage.

Comment: I made an external api on my server and then I am accessing this link from my own server because it is giving me security check .